# How to suppress warnings for FIXME comment in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, sonarqube, sonarlint, sonarlint-eclipse

I am developing a Java application and Using SonarLint to test the code quality.
Sonar shows the error : **Take the required action to fix the issue indicated by this comment.**

For below line of code:

```
// FIXME: temp here until we drop tomee or remove all exceptions from ejb <-> non-ejb path.
```

Is there any way I can suppress the warning in SonarLint ?

Comment: That doesn't sound like the kind of compiler feedback you want to be ignoring. If it is, maybe the comment doesn't warrant a FIXME tag.

Comment: Even TODO comment tags show errors, but since they are minor, does not bothers me. But the FIXME warnings are major, due to which code quality issue is coming.

Comment: If it's not important, then why not demote `FIXME` to `TODO`?

Comment: I think that will be last option, if I could not get anything useful.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the **connected mode** to bind your project in the IDE to a project in SonarQube. **SonarLint will use the same code analyzers and rules as the ones in SonarQube**.

In SonarQube, it's possible to change the quality profile assigned to projects and in this way, to **enable or disable rules**.

More information: https://www.sonarlint.org/intellij/howto.html

Comment: thanks for the link. I have already tried the integration. Seems I have to take care of the code rather than to change the quality criteria.

Answer (score 2):

I checked several places and tried many things to suppress the warnings, but turns out that `//FIXME` are considered as `major warnings` in `Sonar` . You need to take care of them by removing the tag and fixing the issue which was mentioned in the tag (by the developer of tag). 
 
Or you can simply remove the tag if that issue is not needed to be fixed or that is itself not an issue now.